# Rails add_column with a limit and default with Postgres Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgres-9.4

I'm trying to add a column that defaults to a generated UUID without the hyphens as a varchar(32). Currently this is what my migration has:

```
add_column :users, :uuid, :string, limit: 32, default: "REPLACE(uuid_generate_v4(), '-', '')"
```

But it seems to error out because it's just setting that as string text:

> PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(32)

I can't seem to find proper documentation on setting a default value to an sql statement, but that it might be simpler to do in Rails 5 (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20005)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Well I was able to find your answer. Active Record (apparently) has some postgresql specific support. If you're using postgresql 9.4+ and Active Record, you can make use of UUID's in your schema. [There's an official Rails guide that describes how to do it here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#uuid).

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE**

I don't know how to set this at the database level, but you can add a default to the Active Record model [using a callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) like so:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create do
    if self.uuid.nil?
      self.uuid = REPLACE(uuid_generate_v4(), '-', '')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would that run? My example was postgres functions and not ruby but the way I do it in ruby is in `before_create` (so only runs once) with `self.uuid ||= SecureRandom.uuid.gsub("-", "")` (`||` so that you can choose to set it manually). I'm mostly just interested in being able to do it in the postgres side of things

Comment: You're totally right, before validate would not work as it would also fire on update. I have no idea about the function, I was just copying from your example. That being said, since you're using postgresql (as evinced by your error statement), I found your solution and updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, reading through all of that link, Active Record actually supports a lot of postgresql specific features.

Comment: Since you obviously have some sql knowledge, don't suppose you know the answer to this question I posted earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580266/order-by-columns-that-are-sometimes-empty-using-active-record-rails